# How to create perfectly white Elevated Button with Material3 with elevation?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, material3

I am working on an ElevatedButton style in Flutter and I try to make it perfectly white inside with some elevation, but I can't achieve it.
Here is my style:

```
ButtonStyle(
elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all(5), 
backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
    Colors.white), 
)
```

But when I try to actually use it the button isn't white, but a little bit darker.

[image]

Also when I try any other color with elevation the same thing happens and the colors aren't perfectly adequate.

I found out there is a thing called surfaceTintColor which seems to change the exact color of a button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Result:

[image]

You can play around with the `ButtonStyle`/`elevation`:

```dart
 ElevatedButton(
            style: ButtonStyle(
              backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.white),
              foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.white),
              overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.white),
              shadowColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.white),
              elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all<double>(0.1),
            ),
            child: Text(
              'Elevated Button',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
          )
```

Comment: It seems to work just fine, but I also tried to use the thing called surfaceTintColor with the same color I use for backgroundColor and it also seems to do the job.